# How to keep first level list elements in a multi level nested list of lists

Tags: r, purrr

I have a list with many levels. I want to only keep elements at the 1st level.

Example list:

```
 my_list <-
   list(
    a.1 = "some text",
    b.1 = NA,
    c.1 = integer(0),
    d.1 = "some text",
    e.1 = list(a.2 = "some text", b.2 = "a2"),
    f.1 = list(c.2 = "some text", d.2 = integer(10), e.2 = list(a.3 = "some deep text"))
   )
```

... and I'd like to end up with:

```
 my_list2 <-
   list(
     a.1 = "some text",
     b.1 = NA,
     c.1 = integer(0),
     d.1 = "some text"
   )
```

Given the real list is messy and many levels deep I'd like to be able to use something like `purrr::keep` to simply remove further nested items.

I have tried using `keep` but the predicate functions throw back errors:

```
 map_depth(my_list, 1, ~ keep(.x, vec_depth(.x) > 1))
```

> Error in probe(.x, .p, ...) : length(.p) == length(.x) is not TRUE

Thanks.

Comment: Hi @nycrefugee! The title suggests a rather general problem. However, in the question body, you have a very specific requirement: "_I want to only keep elements at the 1st level_". You may consider to edit the title to agree with your actual issue, to make it easier to find the question for future visitors with the same problem. Cheers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Or maybe this solution in tidyverse:

```
library(purrr)

my_list %>% 
  keep(~ vec_depth(.x) == 1)

$a.1
[1] "some text"

$b.1
[1] NA

$c.1
integer(0)

$d.1
[1] "some text"
```

Comment: Just came here to post `keep(my_list, ~vec_depth(.) == 1)`.  I actually think that [@nycrefugee](https://stackoverflow.com/u/7871804) is already using [**`purrr`**](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/), as indicated by their last code block.

Comment: Yes but he used `keep` in `map_depth` which is not necessary in this case. I tried to just modify his own solution.

Comment: Correct.  I was simply confirming that your solution is ideal, since it simply fixes the existing attempt in **`purrr`**, which is already in the **`tidyverse`**.  No paradigm shift is necessary.

Comment: `vec_depth` seems like an interesting function! got to know it thanks to this question. Haven't been using R for quite some time.

Comment: `vec_depth()` might be interesting, but it can have really infuriating implications for `map_depth()`.   Since `vec_depth()` throws an error whenever it encounters an object other than a vector or list, I've had to alter the source code as a developer, in order to `map_*()` the penultimate level of a ragged tree containing a diversity of objects.  I'll probably post a question to SO in the near future, in search of a more elegant fix.

Answer (score 3):

You could subset your list to only include items that are not themselves lists using:

```r
my_list[!sapply(my_list, is.list)]
#> $a.1
#> [1] "some text"
#>
#> $b.1
#> [1] NA
#>
#> $c.1
#> integer(0)
#>
#> $d.1
#> [1] "some text"
```

Comment: I amended the example above to be another level deep.

Comment: @nycrefugee you can use `my_list[!sapply(my_list, function(x) purrr::vec_depth(x) > 1)]`, then just increase the 1 to whatever depth you want to keep

Comment: @AllanCameron At that point, why not just fix [@nycrefugee](https://stackoverflow.com/u/7871804)'s original code in [**`purrr`**](https://purrr.tidyverse.org): `keep(my_list, ~vec_depth(.) == 1))`?

Answer (score 2):

Using `collapse::atomic_elem` to "extract [...] the atomic [...] elements at the top-level of the list tree"

```
collapse::atomic_elem(my_list)
# $a.1
# [1] "some text"
#
# $b.1
# [1] NA
#
# $c.1
# integer(0)
# 
# $d.1
# [1] "some text"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try `Filter` + `is.list` like below

```
> Filter(Negate(is.list),my_list)
$a.1
[1] "some text"

$b.1
[1] NA

$c.1
integer(0)

$d.1
[1] "some text"
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach using `rrapply::rrapply()` (extended version of base `rapply`):

```
library(rrapply)

rrapply(my_list, condition = \(x, .xpos) length(.xpos) == 1, how = "prune") |>
  str()
#> List of 4
#>  $ a.1: chr "some text"
#>  $ b.1: logi NA
#>  $ c.1: int(0) 
#>  $ d.1: chr "some text"
```

This may be useful as it is easily modified to handle other filter conditions as well. For instance,

```
rrapply(my_list, condition = \(x) x == "some text", how = "prune") |>
  str()
#> List of 4
#>  $ a.1: chr "some text"
#>  $ d.1: chr "some text"
#>  $ e.1:List of 1
#>   ..$ a.2: chr "some text"
#>  $ f.1:List of 1
#>   ..$ c.2: chr "some text"

rrapply(my_list, condition = \(x, .xname) grepl("a", .xname), how = "prune") |>
  str()
#> List of 3
#>  $ a.1: chr "some text"
#>  $ e.1:List of 1
#>   ..$ a.2: chr "some text"
#>  $ f.1:List of 1
#>   ..$ e.2:List of 1
#>   .. ..$ a.3: chr "some deep text"
```